# Android notification click_action meaningless word

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
{
    "to": "FCM token",

    "notification": {
        "title": "this is sample title",
        "body":"this is sample body",
        "click_action": "abc"
    },
    "data": {
        "sequence" : "84"

    } 
}
```

If you enter any word in click_action value and click push notification on the device, there is no response.

Should I put acitvity name in click_action?

```
{
    "to": "FCM token",

    "notification": {
        "title": "this is sample title",
        "body":"this is sample body",
        "click_action": ""
    },
    "data": {
        "sequence" : "84"

    } 
}
```

Is it possible to receive the value of click_action as an empty value in Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle notification clicks properly, you should set the click_action field to a meaningful action. This action should correspond to an activity or intent filter defined in your AndroidManifest.xml file. For example:

```
{
    "to": "FCM token",
    "notification": {
        "title": "This is a sample title",
        "body": "This is a sample body",
        "click_action": "com.example.myapp.MY_CUSTOM_ACTION"
    },
    "data": {
        "sequence" : "84"
    }
}
```

In this example, "com.example.myapp.MY_CUSTOM_ACTION" should match the action specified in your app's manifest file. When the user taps the notification, Android will launch the corresponding activity or perform the specified action.

If you want to receive the click_action as an empty value in your Android app, you can set it to an empty string as you mentioned in your second JSON example. In this case, when the user clicks the notification, your app can check if the click_action is empty and decide on the behavior accordingly.

Good Luck.

-----------added-----------

It's possible to handle the click_action with an empty value. When the user taps the notification, your app can handle it by overriding the onMessageReceived method of your FCM service or by using a notification click handler.

```
"click_action": ""
```

Set click answer to empty as you did.

```
And in your app, override the onMessageReceived method:

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // Handle the received FCM message here, including the notification data and optional click_action.

        // When click_action is empty, you can still handle the notification here.
        // For example, show it in the notification tray or open a specific activity.

        // You can access notification data like this:
        String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        String body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        
        // Handle the notification as needed.
    }
}
```

While click_action is commonly used to specify an explicit action or activity to open when the notification is clicked, you can still handle notifications without it by processing the notification data within your onMessageReceived method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Can't handle click_action with empty value in android? Because click_action is also used in web push

Comment: Yeah I added some contents.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to send the extra parmeters like click_action in Data object not in Notification as they have limit of characters depends device to device

and from Data object you can get the value as

```
   val json = JSONObject(remoteMessage.data.toString())
   val data = json.getJSONObject("data")
   val click_action = data.getString("click_action ")
```

and by following code you can select the particular activity and pass the data in that activity

```
var resultIntent = Intent(applicationContext, SplashActivity::class.java)
resultIntent.putExtra("title", title)
resultIntent.putExtra("click_action", click_action)
```

And set this intent as PendingIntent  (I have used this in other class as Notification Utils)

```
  val icon = R.mipmap.ic_launcher
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
        val resultPendingIntent :PendingIntent ;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 31) {
            resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                mContext,
                Random().nextInt(),
                intent,
                 PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
            )
        } else {
            resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                mContext,
                Random().nextInt(),
                intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
            )
        }
```

And set it as content intent

```
val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(
            mContext, channelId
        )/*
        notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
            */
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .setStyle(bigPictureStyle)
            .setWhen(getTimeMilliSec(timeStamp))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.resources, icon))
            .setContentText(message)
```